# Pass image from UIImagePickerController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm reading lots of posts about this but I can't solve my problem...
I'm trying to send an Image from one ViewController with Picker...to another ViewController but the image doesn't appear...

I have 2 VC:

**HomeViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface QuizTypeViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)photo:(id)sender;

@end
```

**HomeViewController.m** (I'm getting the image correctly, i'm going to post just the segue code)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

PhotoViewController *controller = [PhotoViewController new];
controller.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto" sender:self];

}
```

**PhotoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

**PhotoViewController.m** - Nothing...

What I'm doing wrong? I don't know...

Comment: Did you synthesized the imageview?

Comment: @Ramdy In Xcode 5 with `LLVM` there is not need to synthesize and more.

Comment: So, we no need to use synthesize ? @rckoenes

Comment: @Ramdy no, if you use `LLVM` which in now mandatory. You no longer have to add the `@synthesize` in the `.m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT `new` a PhotoViewController. When you call

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto" sender:self];`

A `PhotoViewController` instance will be automatically created for you. What you should do is pass the chosen image to it. And in your `PhotoViewController`'s some method (for example:`viewDidLoad`) to display it.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    PhotoViewController *photoViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    photoViewController.image = self.chosenImage;
}
```

Comment: on viewDidLoad i have to insert this: "self.imageView.image = self.image;"

Answer (score 1):

You create new PhotoViewController in imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: but you don't push/present it in view hierarchy so it will be dismissed. The best way is pass image as a parameter in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
_tmp = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto" sender: chosenImage];

}
```

and in prepareForSegue:segue: method get image from sender and pass it to destination view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // TODO: check segue identifier
    PhotoViewController *vc = (PhotoViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    // Get the image 
    UIImage *img = (UIImage*)sender
    // Pass image to the new view controller.
    vc.imageView.image = img;
    //It can failed because your image view can not be created
    // You should use @property for UIImage, pass img to image and in view did load
    //assign imageView.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto" sender:self];` will create a new instance of the ViewController by itself.

If you want it to show your instance you need to show with `[self presentViewController :viewController animated:YES]` or similar

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

  UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 _tmp = chosenImage;

  PhotoViewController *controller    = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto"];
controller.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self presentViewController:controlle animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HomeViewController.m

```
PhotoViewController *controller = [PhotoViewController new];
controller.image = chosenImage;
```

PhotoViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

PhotoViewController.m

```
imageView.image = image;
```